# Doubly linked list does not create properly

Tags: c, list, pointers

I am trying to create a doubly linked list in C but it doesn't work and I don't know why. It prints only the last element that I introduce. I do not see any problem at the part of code that creates the list. Maybe you can see it?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct node
{
    int data;
    struct node *next;
    struct node *prev;
}NodeT;

struct d_linked_list
{
   NodeT *first;
   NodeT *last;
};

int main()
{
    int d;
    struct d_linked_list *l;
    NodeT *p,*q;
    p=(NodeT*)malloc(sizeof(NodeT));
    q=(NodeT*)malloc(sizeof(NodeT));
    l->first=NULL;
    l->last=NULL;
    while (fscanf(stdin,"%d",&d)!=EOF)
    {
        p->data=d;
        if (l->first==NULL)
        {
            l->first=p;
            l->last=p;
            p->next=NULL;
            p->prev=NULL;
        }
        else
        {
            l->last->next=p;
            p->prev=l->last;
            l->last=p;
        }
    }
    l->last->next=NULL;
    for (q=l->first;q!=NULL;q=q->next)
        printf("%d ",q->data);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You are nearly using `fscanf()` correctly, but the test should be `while (fscanf(stdin, "%d", &d) == 1)` because `fscanf()` will return 0 when it fails to read an integer because the input contains, for example, a letter instead.  That is, however, unrelated to the construction of the list.

Answer (score 2):

As so often, there are a number of problems, some of them already identified in other answers or in comments and some (I think) not identified before:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct node
{
    int data;
    struct node *next;
    struct node *prev;
}NodeT;

struct d_linked_list
{
   NodeT *first;
   NodeT *last;
};
```

So far, so good.

```
int main()
{
    int d;
    struct d_linked_list *l;
```

You don't allocate space for `l`.  It would probably be simpler (maybe better, therefore) to use:

```
struct d_linked_list head;  // Or maybe list instead of head
```

and then refer to `head` in your code instead of `l`; you could also use `l = &head;` without further changes.

```
    NodeT *p,*q;
    p=(NodeT*)malloc(sizeof(NodeT));
    q=(NodeT*)malloc(sizeof(NodeT));
```

You never use the space allocated for `q` and you eventually overwrite it, thus leaking.  You should check that `malloc()` worked, doing something appropriate (stop with an error message?) if it has failed.

```
    l->first=NULL;
    l->last=NULL;
    while (fscanf(stdin,"%d",&d)!=EOF)
```

You should check that you got one integer with `while (fscanf(stdin, "%d", &d) == 1)`; the loop breaks on EOF or on a conversion failure.

```
    {
        p->data=d;
```

You allocated `p` before the loop, but each subsequent entry is overwriting the same space.  You need to allocate a new node for each value you read.  (This was not previously identified as an issue — though I see [Filipe Gonçalves](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2793118/filipe-goncalves) added it to his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22439218/15168) while I was typing mine.)

```
        if (l->first==NULL)
        {
            l->first=p;
            l->last=p;
            p->next=NULL;
            p->prev=NULL;
        }
        else
        {
            l->last->next=p;
            p->prev=l->last;
            l->last=p;
        }
    }
```

<s>Superficially, the code above looks OK; I've not run it, so there could be issues I've not spotted.</s>

*I noted 'not thoroughly checked' and indeed there are problems, as Filipe pointed out.  The `if` clause is OK, I think, but the `else` clause needs to set `p->next = NULL;`.  In general, it is a good idea to create the node completely: `p->data = d; p->next = NULL; p->prev = NULL:` and then hook the node into the list.*

```
    l->last->next=NULL;
```

This line should be unnecessary.  At the end of each cycle of the loop, the list should be correctly formed.  One way to test this is to print out the contents of the list (using a function) on each cycle.  You'd also use that function in place of the loop that follows.  An interface design that I often use is:

```
void dump_list(FILE *fp, char const *tag, struct d_linked_list const *list)
```

which prints the identifying tag and the contents of the list on the given file stream.  I keep such functions around for every significant data structure so that debugging is easier later.

```
    for (q=l->first;q!=NULL;q=q->next)
```

This loop loses track of the space allocated to `q`.

```
        printf("%d ",q->data);
```

You should output a newline at some point.

You should also go through the motions of releasing all the space allocated, simply to make sure you know how you could do that.  When you're about to exit a program, it isn't crucial, but if you were using the list in a long-running program that needs a list once a minute, then goes off and does unrelated operations, then you'd be leaking all that memory and your long-running program would stop running after a while because it lacked the necessary memory (because it had leaked — wasted — the memory in the lists).

```
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: +1, brilliant answer, as usual! But note that `l->last->next=NULL;` is indeed necessary after the loop, since the original code never initializes `p->next`. A small fix would be to initialize both `p->prev` and `p->next` to NULL after allocating `p`, like I showed in my answer (and removing the equivalent assignments inside `if (l->first == NULL) { ... }`).

Comment: @FilipeGonçalves: Yup, I agree...it was in the bit that looks 'superficially OK'.  It was a bit superficial.  I'm going to go back and add some commentary.

Answer (score 1):

Try moving `p=(NodeT*)malloc(sizeof(NodeT));` into the top of the loop. Also, you don't need to `malloc` the value in `q`.

Answer (score 1):

You never allocate space for `l`. Therefore, these lines are dereferencing an invalid pointer:

```
l->first=NULL;
l->last=NULL;
```

You must allocate space for `l` before using it:

```
l = malloc(sizeof(*l));
l->first=NULL;
l->last=NULL;
```

Also, you need to allocate a new element for each new value that you read. Thus, I would move the allocation for `p` into the loop:

```
q=(NodeT*)malloc(sizeof(NodeT));
l->first=NULL;
l->last=NULL;
while (fscanf(stdin,"%d",&d)!=EOF)
{
    p=(NodeT*)malloc(sizeof(NodeT));
    /* ... */
}
```

And you don't need to allocate space for `q` (you use it only for traversing the list). Finally, as pointed out in a comment, you should check if `fscanf()` returned 1, because only in that case you can be sure that `d` contains a valid value.

Putting this all together:

```
int main()
{
    int d;
    struct d_linked_list *l;
    NodeT *p,*q;
    if ((l = malloc(sizeof(*l))) == NULL) {
        /* Handle malloc error */
    }
    l->first=NULL;
    l->last=NULL;
    while (fscanf(stdin,"%d",&d) == 1)
    {
        if ((p = malloc(sizeof(*p))) == NULL) {
            /* Handle malloc error... */
        }
        p->data=d;
        p->next = p->prev = NULL;
        if (l->first==NULL)
        {
            l->first=p;
            l->last=p;
        }
        else
        {
            l->last->next=p;
            p->prev=l->last;
            l->last=p;
        }
    }
    for (q=l->first;q!=NULL;q=q->next)
        printf("%d ",q->data);
    return 0;
}
```

**UPDATE**: I changed the code to check for `malloc()`'s return value, and took that `l->last->next = NULL;` away - `p->next` and `p->prev` are now initialized to `NULL` inside the loop, there is no need to do it after the loop.

Comment: Test that `malloc()` succeeded?  What does the `l->last->next = NULL;` assignment after the loop do?  The main loop body should have set all the pointers that need setting, shouldn't it?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Added the `malloc()` test, thanks for noticing. About the assignment after the loop: yep, it's a little bit ugly, it stayed there because I copied OP's code. It was necessary because the loop always left `l->last->next` uninitialized. Anyway, I deleted it, and moved pointers initialization inside the loop.